# Is Nest 3rd Gen Thermostat compatible as a replacement for Honeywell TH3110D1008

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, nest

I have an Ultra-Zone EWC-ST-2E controller unit for my gas AC unit at home (heating and cooling). 
It is set for two zones. Where the first zone has to be on (heating or cooling) in order to enable to operation of the second zone.

Both zones have Honeywell TH3110D1008 thermostats with the following pins: W, Y, G, O Rc, R, B, C

The first zone has the following wires in: W, Y, G, O, R, B
The second zone has the following wires: W, Y, G, O, Rc

Is a Nest 3rd generation thermostat compatible with this setup/system?

Below are images of the main AC controller diagram and snapshot, as well as wiring of both zones.

Lastly, can anyone also explain what are the different wires for/meaning?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here are more pictures of a pump or so that sits on teh floor next to the heaitng/cooling unit:
[image]

Here is a picture of the inside of the heating/cooling unit:
[image]

The bottom part has this controller unit:
[image]

Comment: Have you contacted Nest, or checked their online help?  Nest maintains a fairly extensive list of compatible equipment.

Comment: Can you post some higher quality photos of the zone controller, and zone controller paperwork?

Comment: `R` - 24VAC. `W` - Heat call.  `Y` - Cool call. `G` - Fan.  `O` - Heat pump changeover (cooling).  `B` - Heat pump changeover (heating). `C` - Common (24 VAC).

Comment: Thanks for the letters breakdown. I have added higher res images.

Comment: I'm not sure why the `O` and `B` wires are used with the zone1 thermostat,  it doesn't appear you have a heat pump. Is the thermostat set up for a heat pump, or for a gas furnace with air conditioner?

Comment: I am not sure. I have added three more pictures. There is some pump next to the whole unit. Then top part of the unit has this motor looking thing, with what it looks like an iron gas pipe coming in. The bottom has something else there, and some controller unit.

Comment: The pump on the floor is probably a condensate pump.  Looks like a gas furnace with an outdoor condensing unit  (A/C unit).  So I'm not sure why `O` and `B` are connected.  You might be able to use the Nest, and just not connect the `O` and `B` wires.  You'll connect `R`, `W`, `G`, and `Y`.  If the Nest requires a `C` wire, you may be able to repurpose the orange or blue wire.